# Configuring SSL in Scalatra

Tags: scala, jetty, scalatra

I've been using Scalatra as a web server and I haven't found any clear instructions on how you're supposed to add ssl certificates/TLS when generating the project using g8. Where do I add the certificate, and what configuration do I have to make to get this to work?

Comment: One approach is to terminate SSL at a proxy, e.g. Nginx. Then continue with HTTP.

Comment: That sounds like a much less painful solution... I'll give it a try. Thanks!